# Saving to plist file issue

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I can't save my new data to plist file for some reason. This is code I have been using for saving data:

```
   -(void)saveData:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryData toFile:(NSString *)filename {
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *path = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
     NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [data addObject:dictionaryData];
    [data writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
     }
```

this is code I used to copy file from bundle to app directory in case if it is not there :

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)loadFromFile:(NSString *)filename {
     NSError *error;
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *path = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
     NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     if(![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSArray *fileArray = [filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *name = [fileArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *ext = [fileArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:ext];
        [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
     }
     NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
     return data;
     }
```

For some reason I can't save new data to plist file. When I try to add new NSMutableDictionary object to my plist file (with saveData:toFile: method) and than reload my array variable with the plist file data - new object is not there. Am I doing something wrong?

this is how I load plist file :

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *modules;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *module; 

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modules = [self loadFromFile:@"ModulesList.plist"];
    self.module = [self.modules objectAtIndex:0];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.modules.count; i++ ) {
        NSLog(@"Modules array from plist file, module at index %i : %@",i, [self.modules         objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

than for testing purpose I have this code to add new module object:

```
    - (IBAction)leftButton:(id)sender {
      NSString *mytitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my title"];
      NSString *myauthor = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my author2"];
      NSUInteger myean = 22023423;
      NSString *mytitle2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my title 2"];
      NSString *myauthor2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my author2"];
      NSUInteger myean2 = 29032432;
      NSString *mytitle3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my title 3"];
      NSString *myauthor3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my author 3"];
      NSUInteger myean3 = 21023423;


      NSMutableDictionary *mybook = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      NSMutableDictionary *mybook2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      NSMutableDictionary *mybook3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

      [mybook setObject:mytitle forKey:@"title"];
      [mybook setObject:myauthor forKey:@"author"];
      [mybook setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myean] forKey:@"ean"];

      [mybook2 setObject:mytitle2 forKey:@"title"];
      [mybook2 setObject:myauthor2 forKey:@"author"];
      [mybook2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myean2] forKey:@"ean"];

      [mybook3 setObject:mytitle3 forKey:@"title"];
      [mybook3 setObject:myauthor3 forKey:@"author"];
      [mybook3 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myean3] forKey:@"ean"];

      NSMutableArray *mybooks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      [mybooks addObject:mybook];
      [mybooks addObject:mybook2];
      [mybooks addObject:mybook3];

      [self.module setObject:mybooks forKey:@"books"];
      [self.modules addObject:self.module];


      for (int i = 0; i < self.modules.count; i++ ) {
          NSLog(@"Modules array after add operation, module at index: %i: %@",i, [self.modules objectAtIndex:i]);
}

      [self saveData:self.module toFile:@"ModulesList.plist"];   
   }
```

than when I will reload my self.modules array from plist with button action, my new data is not there:

```
       - (IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
         self.modules = [self loadFromFile:@"ModulesList.plist"];
         for (int i = 0; i < self.modules.count; i++ ) {
             NSLog(@"RELOAD: Modules array from plist file, module at index %i : %@",i,[self.modules objectAtIndex:i]);
         }

   }
```

this is screenshot of my plist file : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49076351/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-27%20at%2016.27.45.png

Comment: Add `NSLog("path='%@', path);` before the `initWithContentsOfFile:` call and post what is logs.

Comment: Also add error checking to the `copyItemAtPath:` call.

Comment: log message: path: /var/mobile/Applications/68825CED-FED7-41F7-BAEE-F1D3E0A9299E/Documents/ModulesList.plist

Comment: And does `copyItemAtPath:` succeed?

Comment: yup, there is no error

Comment: Does it return `YES`?

Comment: I mean error object is (null) so I think copyItemAtPath succeed, right?

Comment: Yeah probably, but better is to check the returned value.

Comment: Let me add more code to my question, maybe I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: @user1873508 Does your array contain valid property list objects only? You can't just persist your own classes to disk.

Comment: I think so. this is screenshoot of my plist file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49076351/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-27%20at%2016.27.45.png  My new object that I am trying to add is dictionary with properties: string (title) and 3 arrays (books, notes, grades). Than in books array, each object is dictionary with 3 properties (string, string and NSNumber).